# How to use spring-cloud-starter-config and spring-boot-devtools together?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-boot-devtools

spring-cloud-starter-config on its own works perfectly as well as spring-boot-devtools, but when I create a project that uses both I get this error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)

2021-09-23 11:14:28.630  WARN 24140 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: None of labels [] found
2021-09-23 11:14:28.784  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=47535484-8956-3009-8fe1-7c3ac7203bb9
2021-09-23 11:14:28.815  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-23 11:14:28.815  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-23 11:14:28.815  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
2021-09-23 11:14:28.831  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-23 11:14:28.831  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 201 ms
2021-09-23 11:14:28.831  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] com.xxx.otp.sample.Starter               : Active profiles22: local_dev
2021-09-23 11:14:28.868  WARN 24140 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
2021-09-23 11:14:28.868  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-09-23 11:14:28.884  INFO 24140 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-23 11:14:28.900 ERROR 24140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.xxx.otp.sample.Starter.main(Starter.java:18) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.java:129) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

The bootstrap-local_dev.yaml:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery:
      enabled: false
    config:
      uri:
```

All other yaml and properties files are blank.
Only environment variable set is:

```
SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES=local_dev
```

The pom.xml parent is:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version><!-- This version must match the version in com.bmw.otp:dependencies:pom.xml -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

The dependencies section in pom.xml is:

```xml
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- Required by spring-cloud-starter-config -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provided dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Is there anything special that I need to configure or setup to get the benefit of both spring-cloud-starter-config and spring-boot-devtools in the same project?

Comment: Hi, can you post the whole pom.xml and not just sections? `<dependencyManagement>` section is also important. How you generated this pom? did you use the Spring Initializr or on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your `pom.xml` via [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and the following pom.xml manages to start the SpringBootApplication successfully.
You can cross-check it with yours, just some quick points:

- `spring-boot-starter` is not needed since you have `spring-boot-starter-web`
- `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` is not required (at least Spring Initializr didn't put it along with `spring-cloud-starter-config`
- I didn't include `spring-batch-test` and `spring-security-test` since it doesn't seem that you use the relevant starters.

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!--        runtime dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <!--        test dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
  ```

Moreover it needed to add the following line in the `appplication.properties` file:

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:
```

Comment: spring-boot-starter is indeed unnecessary, spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap got rid of the error message "Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration." but I guess it probably configured something that clashes with spring-boot-dev-tools. When I disable the config client without the spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap, the dev-tools work and in prod where I need the config client, I don't need the dev-tools so that is okay.